# How can I plot theano.tensor value?

Tags: python, debugging, opencv, theano

To visualize TensorType(float64, matrix) as an image using imshow, How could I that?I cannot directly use imshow on Tensor since it gives me this error

```
mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

When I try to convert datatype to array using numpy.asarray  I get

```
 mat data type = 17 is not supported
```

Is there any way to convert to uint8 datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theano tensors are symbolic variables, with no value attached to them. If you want to plot something it is probably a shared variable (the weights of your network), in which case you can grab the values with `my_shared.get_value()`, or the output of the network when you pass an input, in which case I believe it should already be a numpy array.